# Lattice points visible from the origin

Tags: code-golf, math, ascii-art

## Challenge

Create a program that outputs a square grid showing *visible* and *non-visible* points \$(x, y)\$ from the origin based on their greatest common divisor (GCD).

A point \$(x, y)\$ is considered [*visible*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VisiblePoint.html) from the origin \$(0, 0)\$ if the \$\gcd(x, y) = 1\$. Otherwise, it's *non-visible*.

[image: x_y]

**Input**

An integer \$n\$, representing the radius of the square grid from the origin along both \$x\$ and \$y\$ axes.

**Output**

A square grid centered at the origin, where each cell is:

- ". " (dot followed by a space) for a *visible* point
- "\$\ \ \$" (two spaces) for a *non-visible* point

## Examples

Length from the origin: **n = 6**

```
  .       .   .       .   
.   . . . .   . . . .   . 
  .   .   .   .   .   .   
  . .   . .   . .   . .   
  .   .   .   .   .   .   
. . . . . . . . . . . . . 
          .   .           
. . . . . . . . . . . . . 
  .   .   .   .   .   .   
  . .   . .   . .   . .   
  .   .   .   .   .   .   
.   . . . .   . . . .   . 
  .       .   .       .
```

Length from the origin: **n = 5**

```
  . . . .   . . . .   
.   .   .   .   .   . 
. .   . .   . .   . . 
.   .   .   .   .   . 
. . . . . . . . . . . 
        .   .         
. . . . . . . . . . . 
.   .   .   .   .   . 
. .   . .   . .   . . 
.   .   .   .   .   . 
  . . . .   . . . .
```

Length from the origin: **n = 4**

```
  .   .   .   .   
.   . .   . .   . 
  .   .   .   .   
. . . . . . . . . 
      .   .       
. . . . . . . . . 
  .   .   .   .   
.   . .   . .   . 
  .   .   .   .
```

Length from the origin: **n = 3**

```
  . .   . .   
.   .   .   . 
. . . . . . . 
    .   .     
. . . . . . . 
.   .   .   . 
  . .   . .
```

Length from the origin: **n = 2**

```
  .   .   
. . . . . 
  .   .   
. . . . . 
  .   .
```

Length from the origin: **n = 1**

```
. . . 
.   . 
. . .
```

## References

[Visible Points in a Lattice](https://www.geogebra.org/m/Er2NcQRT)

[Visible Point -- from Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VisiblePoint.html)

[Lattice points visible from the origin](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/11/07/lattice-points-visible-from-the-origin/)

Comment: Is it necessary to output the trailing spaces on each line?

Comment: Shouldn’t the lattice point `(0, 0)` a. k. a. the origin be marked, too? I mean it is “visible” from the origin. The line of sight has a length of zero, but this should not harm the mathematical conception of “visibility”, right? May we be allowed to mark or leave the origin unmarked at our discretion?

Comment: For a [visible lattice point](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VisiblePoint.html), by definition is \$gcd(x, y) = 1\$. So, the origin (0,0) should not have it marked as visible.

Comment: Is it allowed to output with a different format (e.g. as a matrix, graphical output, etc.)?

Comment: @wheatwizard, why remove the image from the post? The text in the first section now refers to four dashed line segments, but they're nowhere to be seen.

Comment: @ilkkachu Unfortunately (potential) copyright infringement: The (most probable) [source](https://DOI.org/10.2140/involve.2021.14.283) of the image does not indicate that the image may be re‑released under a CC‑By‑SA [license](/help/licensing) here, nor did vengy disclose he/she is known as Austin, אבא, or Jasmine (the authors’ first names of the original source) in real life (thus a co‑owner of copyright).

Comment: The references section did have a [link](https://people.uwec.edu/mbirika/paper_lattice_point_visibility.pdf) to the original source of that image and authors. Although it sounds like that wasn't sufficient.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 12 bytes

```
rNgþ`=1ị⁾. G
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCJyTmfDvmA9MeG7i+KBvi4gRyIsIiIsIiIsWyI2Il1d)

-3 bytes thanks to totallyhuman (-1 myself on top of this)

#### Explanation

```
rNgþ`=1ị⁾. G    Main Link
rN              [n, ..., -n]
  gþ`           Outer product table over GCD
     =1         Check if equal to 1 (vectorizes)
       ị⁾. G    Index into [".", " "] and display as grid
```

Comment: [13 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9@vSCX98L4EW8OHu7sfNe7TU3D///@/GQA). Palindromizing is *expensive*.

Comment: @totallyhuman Oh neat, I didn't realize that'd work properly for negatives. I had a feeling bounce was inefficient but didn't know how else to do it; thanks!

Comment: Thanks for making me feel stupid in turn with the `rN`. :P All these years and I still can't get the hang of this language...

Comment: @totallyhuman lol, chain rules are hard can't blame you :P

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>68</s> 61 bytes

*-7 bytes thanks to [Lynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3852).*

```hs
f n|r<-[-n..n]=unlines[do x<-r;" . "!!min(gcd x y)2:" "|y<-r]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DckxDkAwGAbQq3waA0M7GAzoKYxiEC0a9ZOWRJPevbz1bZPftbUpLaDoOj5wEoJG@ZA1pP2gTrwddy2DAMuyw1CxzgovQlk1DCyGf8d0TIYgcT13fzvkWFCnDw)

`unlines` can be dropped if a list of lines is okay.

Comment: Some byte saves: `f n|r<-[-n..n]=unlines[do x<-r;" . "!!min(gcd x y)2:" "|y<-r]`

Comment: @Lynn `min`! `min`!! I can't believe I spent that long trying to shorten that conditional and didn't think of `min`. Also interesting that do-notation is shorter here... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 30 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Assume `⎕io←0`

```
{↑,⌿'. ' '  '[1≠∘.∨⍨⍵-⍳1+⍵+⍵]}
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=e9Q3NTP/UdsEAwA&c=q37UNlHnUc9@dT0FdSBUUI82fNS54FHHDL1HHSse9QLRVt1HvZsNtYEMEI6tBQA&f=AwA&i=Szu0wlD7Ue9mcwA&r=tio&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

```
{↑,⌿'. ' '  '[1≠∘.∨⍨⍵-⍳1+⍵+⍵]}
                    ⍵-⍳1+⍵+⍵   ⍝ indices ⍵ ⍵-1 ⍵-2 ... 2-⍵ 1-⍵ -⍵
                ∘.∨⍨           ⍝ pairwise GCD
              1≠               ⍝ is not 1
    '. ' '  '[              ]  ⍝ Choose between strings '. ' and '  '.
 ↑,⌿                           ⍝ Combine the strings
```

Comment: Nice! The [output](https://ibb.co/yqCsj5g) looks great!

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 89 bytes

```javascript
n=>{for(y=~n;y++-n;)print((g=(a,b=y)=>x-~n?b?g(b,a%b):(a*a-1?"  ":". ")+g(--x):"")(x=n))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxBCoMwEEX3PcUQWpipRuiqxTB6FZOiwSITURFF9OpWu@rqw3@P97Gj7d9d3Q56fO0V78LZUoUOZ97EzFGkxVDb1TIgekYbO56Js0lvkrvco4vtzVGK9m71I1cAKlUJKIo8aj1RqhThxEK07me1KQcQYHga0GcZlgvAO0gfmjJpgsfipNdF1oLMgSqU3/4rx7HuXw)

#### Commented

```javascript
n => {                  // n = input
  for(                  // main loop:
    y = ~n;             //   start with y = -n - 1
    y++ - n;            //   stop when y = n / increment y afterwards
  )                     //
  print(                // print the next line:
    ( g = (             //   g is a recursive function taking:
        a,              //     an integer a
        b = y           //     and an integer b initialized to y
      ) =>              //
      x - ~n ?          //   if x is greater than -n - 1:
        b ?             //     if b is not 0:
          g(b, a % b)   //       do a recursive call with [a, b] = [b, a mod b]
        :               //     else:
          ( a * a - 1 ? //       if a² is not equal to 1:
              "  "      //         append two spaces
            :           //       else:
              ". "      //         append a period and a space
          ) + g(--x)    //       decrement x and do a recursive call
      :                 //   else:
        ""              //     stop
    )(x = n)            //   initial call to g with a = x = n
  )                     // end of print()
}                       //
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>74</s> 51 bytes

-23 (!) bytes thanks to [Sisyphus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48931/sisyphus)

```ruby
->n{a=-n..n
a.map{|y|a.map{" ."[2[_1.gcd y]]+" "}}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3jXXt8qoTbXXz9PTyuBL1chMLqmsqayAMJQU9pWij6HhDvfTkFIXK2FhtJQWl2tpaiNatBaUlxQpu0WaxIMUaalZZ-Zl5mhC5BQsgNAA)

Comment: double map is shorter than `each_slice`: [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3jXXt8qoTbXXz9PTyrBP1chMLqmsqayAMJQU9pWij6HhDvfTkFIXK2FhtJQWl2tpaiNZdBaUlxQpu0WaxeiX58WAdGmpWWfmZeZoQBQsWQGgA)

Comment: @Sisyphus Thansks for the assist. That's a nice trick, indexing into `2`'s bits.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 107 bytes

*-8 bytes, thanks to ceilingcat*

```c
g(a,b){return b?g(b,a%b):a*a;}x,y;f(l){for(y=~l;y++<l;puts(""))for(x=~l;x++<l;)printf(g(x,y)-1?"  ":". ");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lc1BCoMwEIXhvacIASFTtaDWLkyLF@gR3EQxUdAoMVJF7NGbmtID1M1b/MzHlIEoS2MEYX4Bq6r0pCQqMkEKn7kFpOzE6Db7C@WkhZX3iiz3V0sXz7u1dJj0SDAGsH22ff52GFQjNSeC7BKCMMMI4RSfEQa6mY41koCzOr8rnMtHJYWuEVd9h3RdoV41opEpcqdcYv8K@/d9/gaJBckBcLHgcgDEFsQHQGRBdACEFuzjbOZd8paJ0QTPDw)

Answer (score 2):

## Python+Numpy+Pandas, 152 bytes

```
import numpy as np,pandas
def p(n):pandas.DataFrame([c for c in np.dstack(np.mgrid[-n:n+1,-n:n+1]).reshape(-1,2)if np.gcd(*c)==1]).plot.scatter(x=0,y=1)
```

Outputs a graphical plot (even though this isn't strictly the challenge, but when do you see Pandas in code golf?). Ex, `p(3)`:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 33 bytes

```
Ｅ⊕Ｎ⭆⊕ι§ .∧∨ιλ⬤…²⊕ι∨﹪ιν﹪λν‖Ｏ↗↑←ＵＥ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY0xD4JADIV3f8WFqSSniQ4OMjk4kIgYjD8A7wpcUg5yKYR/f5aERTs07/V9zTNdHcxQU4zP4DxDUY@QexOwR89oRY8TP6b@gwHSVKsXC9b@U06SK@fe4gKJOiTivIUygNOK1owIqtq3CCetfh8lFa4Y7ETDins5bI5Wt022q7AhNFzOGEjqL@@xcm3HWomSdceGhbotjFJ9TLMYz3E/0xc) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｅ⊕Ｎ⭆⊕ι§ .∧∨ιλ⬤…²⊕ι∨﹪ιν﹪λν
```

Draw one octant of the diagram.

```
‖Ｏ↗↑←
```

Reflect to complete the diagram. (The reflections are performed serially, so first the octant is reflected diagonally to create the quadrant, then the other two reflections complete the negative axes.)

```
ＵＥ¹
```

Space the `.`s horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

### Pascal, 238 Bytes

This is a complete `program` as per ISO standard 7185 “Standard Pascal”.

```pascal
program p(input,output);type Z=integer;var n,y:Z;function f(a,b:Z):Z;begin f:=a;if b>0 then f:=f(b,a mod b)end;begin read(n);n:=abs(n);for y:=-n to n do begin for n:=-n to n do write((' .')[ord(f(abs(n),abs(y))=1)+1],' ');writeLn end end.
```

Ungölfed:

```pascal
program latticePointsVisibleFromOrigin(input, output);
    const
        mark = ' .';
    type
        Z = integer;
    var
        n, y: Z;
    { GreatestCommonDivisor for _non­negative_ _integers_ _only_. }
    function greatestCommonDivisor(a, b: Z): Z;
        begin
            greatestCommonDivisor ≔ a;
            if b > 0 then
            begin
                greatestCommonDivisor ≔ greatestCommonDivisor(b, a mod b)
            end
        end;
    { ─── main ────────────────────────────────────────────────── }
    begin
        readLn(input, n);
        n ≔ abs(n);
        
        { In Pascal `for`‑loop limits are evaluated (exactly) once. }
        for y ≔ n downto −n do
        begin
            for n ≔ −n to n do
            begin
                { `+1` because in Pascal `string` indices are one‑based. }
                write(output,
                    mark[ord(greatestCommonDivisor(abs(n), abs(y)) = 1) + 1],
                    ' ')
            end;
            writeLn(output)
        end
    end.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 148 bytes

A port of [@Jordan's Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271719/110802) in Scala.

---

Golfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY4xSwQxFIT7_RWPVO-pGzgVEc8saHFgYSVWYhF3s2s09xKyOd1luX9hZ3ONIviL7t8YPZsZvmEY5v2zr7XTR993omT_qiOL--2xf3gydYJrbRnMkAw3PVyEAFNRALxoB4szQLziRKq6ZZsIFHysUluebt9YVdNvRSssGZIHpjm2PuJwXur5mIVGa1yDw8FIJJc6TLXuzR-qyrZ4abu8jAPJrm4wh2pGQoIA43ojAMRadtGvgmmQ9w73ZyTzutH1I0ZVQYiWk2OMcvl8kzJ0ROvdty-ABZ5Q8Y-bzc5_AA)

```scala
n=>{val a=(-n to n);(for(x<-a;y<-a)yield(x,y)).map{case(x,y)=>if(BigInt(x).gcd(y)==1)". " else"  "}.grouped(n*2+1).foreach(r=> println(r.mkString))}
```

Ungolfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TVBBSsRAEMRrXlHkNKNmQAWR1Qh6WBD0JD5gTCZxNNsTJr26QfISL3vRR_kaO9kowtBDdVcVRX18dYVt7Ml2-7nmKjv73jPh8dkVjDvrCW7DjsoOV22L9wQoXYWlogVuiPUCD-QZ-XQBXm0DK0hlBA4gbTjc-o7_jq31sRNCFSLUBhcZ7Dn66dfovWtKWR-i1_8UzC6SaCatWVmJgcJ2bmYiv4SvoK59LYnURpu6KNW4z3GkkRqkcI3QU8gbJuPZ1NQxrFtXKsI-jnEgfCPJnC2eVAxvo3MbPXFDIzSrl3sWWOsx3ZDIWKpTnQy72ub2flv8AQ)

```scala
object Main extends App {
  def F(n: Int): Unit = {
    val a = (-n to n).toList
    val pairs = for (x <- a; y <- a) yield (x, y)
    val pattern = pairs.map { case (x, y) => if (BigInt(x).gcd(y) == 1) ". " else "  " }
    pattern.grouped(n * 2 + 1).foreach(row => println(row.mkString))
  }

  F(6)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 64 bytes

```
n->[print(concat([if(gcd(i,j)-1,"  ",". ")|j<-r]))|i<-r=[-n..n]]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWNx3ydO2iC4oy80o0kvPzkhNLNKIz0zTSk1M0MnWyNHUNdZQUFJR0lPQUlDRrsmx0i2I1NWsygbRttG6enl5ebCzEnCVpGmaaEOaCBRAaAA)

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 65 bytes

```
Input N
For(I,~N,N
".
For(J,~N,N
Ans+sub(" .",1=gcd(abs(I),abs(J)),1)+" 
End
Disp sub(Ans,2,2N+1
End
```

`~` represents the negative sign. The fifth line ends with a space. The output may be cut off if the input is too large.

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Feb-17)</sup>, 31 bytes

```
⊏:" ."=1◌⊞⍢⊃◿∘±:↘1♭≡⊂0.⌵-⇡+1×2.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAg4oqPOiIgLiI9MeKXjOKKnuKNouKKg-KXv-KImMKxOuKGmDHima3iiaHiioIwLuKMtS3ih6ErMcOXMi4KCuKJoSZwIEYgNQo=)

```
⊏:" ."=1◌⊞⍢⊃◿∘±:↘1♭≡⊂0.⌵-⇡+1×2.
                        -⇡+1×2.  # [-n..n]
                       ⌵         # abs
                      .          # duplicate
               :↘1♭≡⊂0           # interleave zeros
         ⊞⍢⊃◿∘±                  # table by gcd
        ◌                        # pop
      =1                         # where is it equal to one?
⊏:" ."                           # change to string
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
(ŸÄDδ¿Θ»T„. ‡
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9vc2FiaWX//yjFuMOERM60wr/OmMK7VOKAni4g4oCh//8z) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/mquSZV1BaYqWgZO@nw6XkX1oC4en4ufzXOLrjcIvLuS2H9p@bcWh3yKOGeXoKjxoW/tc5tM3@PwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
(              # Negate the (implicit) input-integer
 Ÿ             # Push a list in the range [(implicit) input, -input]
  Ä            # Take the absolute value of each: [n,n-1,...,0,...,n-1,n]
   Dδ¿         # Create a GCD-table of this list:
   D           #  Duplicate the list:
    δ          #  Pop both lists, and apply double-vectorized:
     ¿         #   Greatest Common Divisor
      Θ        # Check which values are 1 (1 if 1; 0 otherwise)
       »       # Join each inner list by spaces, and then each string by newlines
        T      # Push 10
         „.    # Push ". "
            ‡  # Transliterate all 1s to "."s and all 0s to spaces
               # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```